# MATLAB m-function for finding local extrema

Tags: matlab, max, min

I'm not a programmer but i have to do quite simple thing in Matlab. I hope you can help me with that.

I have some sort of data, in column and i need to find local extrema. Any ideas how to write this few code lines?

Comment: what sort of data do you have? ) Matrix, vector, analytical expression? Have you tried matlab help?

Comment: What sort od data? It's numbers like that [43.3091
44.4888,46.0707,47.0104,47.9871,48.7491,49.5883,50.4502,50.9328,50.9886,51.1923,51.5843,52.1417,52.8798,53.6376,54.1762,54.3773,54.1111]

It's matrix. I have googled and find some kind of answears. I think i can use diff function with signum but i don't how to do that ;)

Comment: `min(data_in_vector_form)`, `max(data_in_vector_form)`.

Comment: Hmmm but this doesn't find only one max and one min? Global extrema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that.

1) A simple one is to use [this script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40007-find-local-extrema-places-and-values).

2) If the data is not large, you can write your own algorithm analyzing gradient in each point or analyzing increment:

**1D array**

```
jmin=0;
jmax=0;
for j=2:length(M)-1
    if (M(j)>M(j-1))&&(M(j)>M(j+1))
        jmax=jmax+1;
        max_index(jmax)=j;
        max_value(jmax)=M(j);
    end;
    if (M(j)<M(j-1))&&(M(j)<M(j+1))
        jmin=jmin+1;
        min_index(jmin)=j;
        min_value(jmin)=M(j);
    end;
end;
```

**2D matrix**

```
jmin=0;
jmax=0;
s=size(M);
for j1=2:s(1)-1
    for j2=2:s(2)-1
        if (M(j1,j2)>M(j1-1,j2))&&(M(j1,j2)>M(j1+1,j2))&&(M(j1,j2)>M(j1,j2-1))&&(M(j1,j2)>M(j11,j2+1))
            jmax=jmax+1;
            max_index(jmax)=[j1,j2];
            max_value(jmax)=M(j1,j2);
        end;
        if (M(j1,j2)<M(j1-1,j2))&&(M(j1,j2)<M(j1+1,j2))&&(M(j1,j2)<M(j1,j2-1))&&(M(j1,j2)<M(j11,j2+1))
           jmin=jmin+1;
           min_index(jmin)=[j1,j2];
           min_value(jmin)=M(j1,j2);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

In this algorithm we check max or min for each point relative to the four other neighboring points. This pattern can posses more complicated structure and can contain more points depending on data.

Comment: Yeah i analyse this code and it might be what i searching for. Thanks!

Comment: I have corrected for a matrix. If data are noisy, a single cross of points is not enough. One needs something more complicated.

Comment: Can you explain the code in for loop? I mean " j=2:length(M)-1".
It is mean: do a loop when j equals 2 til lenght of M minus 1?

Comment: yes, the loop starts with second element of the array (matrix) and run till the length minus one

Comment: Each point I compare with four neighbors for the 2D matrix (these four neighboring points forms a cross and i scan whole matrix with this structure). For 1D array, two neighbors are enough, for 3D matrix one needs 6 neighbors minimum

Comment: Ok but with 1D i can start with "(M(j1)>M(j1-1))&&(M(j1)>M(j1+1))" Am i right?

Comment: yes, absolutely, you have a single loop with j=2:length(M)-1

Comment: Great. One last question. This two lines:
max_index(jmax)=[j1,j2];
            max_value(jmax)=M(j1,j2);
First write index of max to the matrix and second value of extremum to M matrix?

Comment: yes, right. In 1D case, they read max_index(jmax)=j; and max_value(jmax)=M(j)

Comment: Excellent! I understand this code and thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have found something similiar but it's find extrema without separate it, i guess.

```
d = diff(a)
for i=1:N-2
         if d(i)==0                
            if sign(d(i-1))~=sign(d(i+1)) 
               maxmin = [maxmin, i];
            end
         elseif sign(d(i))~=sign(d(i+1))   
            maxmin = [maxmin, i+1];       
         end
```

Comment: I have done pretty much this in another post, but I did it more vectorized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081942/getting-fft-peaks-from-data/27085436#27085436 .  Because you only want local maxima, remove the `abs` call to the signal.