# determine index and value of first negative peak

Tags: matlab

I am solving a funcion which uses the  moving average filter to remove noise. How can I determine index and value of first and second negative peak after I apply the filter to input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) on the **negative** of your data, then extract the first two elements to extract the first and second indices of where the negative peaks are located.  Supposing your signal was stored in `f`, you would simply do:

```
[peaks, locs] = findpeaks(-f);
p = peaks(1:2);
loc = locs(1:2);
```

`findpeaks` works by finding local maxima.  If you want to find local minima (i.e. negative peaks), you would apply `findpeaks` to the negative of your signal so that the local minima become local maxima, then apply the same algorithm.  `loc` would contain the first two locations of where the negative peaks are, while `p` will determine those negative peak amplitudes.

However, you'll probably need to play around with the input parameters to `findpeaks`, instead of using the default ones to suit your data, but this should be enough to get you started.

---

## Sidenote

If you don't have access to `findpeaks`, take a look at [this post that I wrote to find peaks for FFT data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081942/getting-fft-peaks-from-data/27085436#27085436).  The data is different, but the overall logic is the same.  However, this finds **all** peaks - both local maxima and minima.  If you just want to find the minima, simply look at the negative of the signal rather than the absolute value.