# How to label plot having peaks in matlab

Tags: matlab, label

I'm trying to label my XRD data which have peaks, and I want to label it from my array of data:

```
  peak label  
    ab
    ac
    ad
    cb
    bb
    ba
```

See picture below

[image]

I also want those labels to be vertically aligned on the top of the peaks.
I tried the `findpeaks` function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (but you need to have a Signal Processing Toobox):

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 
y = [1 4 2 7 3 9 5 10 2]
[peak, peakId] = findpeaks(y); %find peaks in your serie
figure(1) 
plot(x, y)
lbalph=('a':'z').'
lb=strcat(Alphabet(1),lbalph(1:length(peak))) %Create a label matrix
lb = num2cell(lb,2) % Convert to cell array
lbid = 1:length(lb)
text(x(peakId), peak, lb(lbid),'Rotation',90) % label the peak with your lb matrix
```

[image]

As you have the index peaks, you can labeled as you want.

Comment: where can i download or get that?

Comment: Depends what your matlab license. Do you know the peaks values?

Comment: what '%6.3 f' mean? where exactly my peak label will be substituted in that code?

Comment: sir, the label was base on what are the values of the peaks, not what my desired label was

Comment: i tried it but it gives an error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Try with your data?What the dimension of your data, x,y,lb?

Comment: i think it's not applicable for data like xrd plot.

Comment: Why? Is not this a x,y data? Or the peak concept in function?

Comment: the x(peak ID) = 6x1 and may peak label dimension is also 6x1

Comment: This is the problem, so put or `x'` or `lb'`.

Comment: i'm wondering if its compatible if your peak label is string cell not number cell

Comment: sir i tried what you said, my peak label become 1x6 and x(peakId) is still 6x1 but it gives the same error.

Comment: base on your code the label is base on the peakId values  where peaks in x-axis was located, i want ,my label come from my desired cell array, look my problem above.

Comment: @Raldenors I automatize the label matrix create.

Comment: Here's an answer for finding peaks if you don't have `findpeaks`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081942/getting-fft-peaks-from-data/27085436#27085436